# Swift - Detecting whether item was inserted into NSMutableSet

Tags: swift, set

This is more for interest rather than a problem, but I have an `NSMutableSet`, retrieved from `UserDefaults` and my objective is to append an item to it and then write it back. I am using an `NSMutableSet` because I only want unique items to be inserted.

The type of object to be inserted is a custom class, I have overrode `hashCode` and `isEqual`.

```
var stopSet: NSMutableSet = []

if let ud = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "favStops") as? Data {
  stopSet = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: ud) as! NSMutableSet
}

stopSet.add(self.theStop!)

let outData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: stopSet)
UserDefaults.standard.set(outData, forKey: "favStops")
NSLog("Saved to UserDefaults")
```

I get the set, call `mySet.add(obj)` and then write the set back to UserDefaults. Everything seems to work fine and (as far as I can see) there don't appear to be duplicates.

However is it possible to tell whether a call to `mySet.add(obj)` actually caused an item to be written to the set. `mySet.add(obj)` doesn't have a return value and if you use Playgrounds (rather than a project) you get in the output on the right hand side an indication of whether the set was actually changed based on the method call.

I know sets are not meant to store duplicate objects so in theory I should just trust that, but I was just wondering if the set did return a response that you could access - as opposed to just getting the length before the insert and after if I really wanted to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has its own native type, `Set`, so you should use it instead of `NSMutableSet`.

Set's `insert` method actually returns a `Bool` indicating whether the insertion succeeded or not, which you can see in the function signature:
`mutating func insert(_ newMember: Element) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Element)`

The following test code showcases this behaviour:

```
var set = Set<Int>()
let (inserted, element) = set.insert(0)
let (again, newElement) = set.insert(0)

print(inserted,element) //true, 0
print(again,oldElement) //false,0
```

The second value of the tuple returns the newly inserted element in case the insertion succeeded and the oldElement otherwise. `oldElement` is not necessarily equal in every aspect to the element you tried to insert. (since for custom types you might define the `isEqual` method in a way that doesn't compare each property of the type).

You don't need to handle the return value of the `insert` function, there is no compiler warning if you just write insert like this:

```
set.insert(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I was playing around in Playgrounds I was using `Set` which gave me the response from the method signature you illustrated.

For some reason I didn't think `Set` conformed to `NSCoding` so that's why I used the bridged variant instead - but it seems like it does (now?!)

Comment: You are right, it doesn't conform to `NSCoding` by default, but it can be bridged to `NSSet` when `Element` can be bridge to a Foundation or when `Element` is a class and since for your case, `Element` is of type `Data`, that is both a class and can be bridged to `NSData`, hence the compiler takes care of this automatically.